# Realizar consulta con varias columnas y un count

Tags: mysql

Necesito sacar una consulta de cuántos eventos hubo en una ciudad por ciudad.
Actualmente tengo esta consulta que me saca el nombre de la ciudad y el número de eventos que ha habido en una ciudad:

```
SELECT ci.name as name, COUNT(*) as num
FROM ciudad ci, evento e, local l
WHERE e.idlocal = l.id
AND l.idciudad = ci.id 
GROUP BY NAME;
```

Esto me devuelve:

| Name | NUM |
| --- | --- |
| Madrid | 35 |
| Barcelona | 24 |
| Valencia | 5 |
| Sevilla | 3 |

El problema es que quiero sacar el identificador de la ciudad para a posteriori cuando pinchen en el html vaya a un identificador concreto de ciudad.

El resultado esperado sería el siguiente:

| ID | NAME | NUM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Madrid | 35 |
| 3 | Barcelona | 24 |
| 4 | Valencia | 5 |
| 5 | Sevilla | 3 |

¿Cómo podría sacar esto?
No me deja añadir en el select un campo más porque me da error en la consulta por el COUNT.

Comment: ¿Tiene alguna relación "java" con la pregunta? (Y "php", y "laravel"...) Y podés agregar un campo más en el SELECT, pero _también tenés que agregarlo en el GROUP BY_.

Comment: Muchas gracias, si, son los lenguajes en los cuales estaba usando esta sentencia, igual no aplicaba para la pregunta. De igual manera, me has dado la solución que estaba buscando, mil gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sin estructuras y algun ejemplo es mas díficil comprender el inconveniente pero a priori lo único que deberías cambiar es el nivel de la agregación.

```
SELECT ci.id, ci.name as name, COUNT(*) as num
FROM ciudad ci, evento e, local l
WHERE e.idlocal = l.id
   AND l.idciudad = ci.id 
GROUP BY ci.id, ci.name;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, esto era lo que buscaba y no daba con la tecla. Perdonad que no haya puesto un ejemplo más claro, estaba tan nublado con el problema que igual no he sabido contextualizar lo suficiente. Muchas gracias por la respuesta.